# Rename files Mac Terminal Command Line to match list

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I have bunch of files that are named

190307_M05898_0065_000000000-CC66F_1_**11570BP0321L01**_1.fastq.gz

190307_M05898_0065_000000000-CC66F_1_**11570BP0321L01**_2.fastq.gz

190307_M05898_0065_000000000-CC66F_1_**11570BP0322L01**_1.fastq.gz

190307_M05898_0065_000000000-CC66F_1_**11570BP0322L01**_2.fastq.gz

etc...

They are all paired with _1 and _2 marking the difference. I've highlighted the difference between each pair in bold. I have a made a .csv with one column containing the **bold** ID and the new ID I want to replace the entire string with.

[image]

Using the command line how do I say "find this specific string from column 1 and replace with the new ID in column 2" but also keep everything after the specific string (i.e. _1.fastq.gz or _2.fastq.gz)

I would like to end up with:

BK1_1.fastq.gz

BK1_2.fastq.gz

BN46_1.fastq.gz

BN46_2.fastq.gz

Edit:

If it helps, I've also created a csv with the full file names not just the IDs

[image]

Comment: What shell are you using? Also are the columns comma seperated?

Comment: bash? i think? and yeah it's saved as csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your file containing the complete file names you can do:

```
IFS=",";
while read fil fil1;
do 
   echo "mv -f $fil $fil1";
   # mv -f "$fil" "$fil1"
done < file
```

Set the input field separator to "," (IFS) and then read the file (the csv file) into a while loop, reading each csv as variables fil and fil1. Use these variables to print the required mv command. Once you have verified that the commands look as expected, comment out the actual command.